# Full Calendar set default view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to set `DefaultView` without using the method `changeview`. I tried this code but it does not work.

```
 $jagenda('#calendar<%=i%>').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: '',
                    center: '',
                    right: ''
                },                
                height: 730,
                minTime: '08:00:00',
                maxTime: '21:00:00',
                scrollTime: '08:00:00',
                defaultView: 'agendaDay',
                timeFormat: ' ',
```

Comment: 'Does not work' is a bit ambigious. Can you provide more information?

Comment: defaultview doesn't change to agendaDay it remains in month

Comment: The code you provided works: http://jsfiddle.net/4chtod2d/1/

Comment: Provide what error comes in console. There could be 100 different reasons it doesn't work. Without proper error message we can't debug

Comment: fullcalendar.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null

Comment: if i add          '$jagenda('.agenda_singola').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');' Work